# <br>,<h1>,<p> tag of HTML not working properly with UILabel attributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

`<br>`,`<h1>`,`<p>` tag not impacting the attributed text it should give 1 line break when I use html string in UILabel

below is my code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UYLCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel* lineLabel = [cell viewWithTag:100];
lineLabel.numberOfLines=0;
NSString* html = self.offerArray[indexPath.row][@"description"];
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@</body></html>",kHTMLHeadOffer,html];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];
lineLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Html sample

```
<h2><font color="gray”>Offer</font></h2>
<b><font color="red">Offer 1:</font></b><br>
<b>1 kg Sugar Free!</b><br>
<p>Every purchase above 500 <br>
valid till 23rd April</p>
```

Result of above in simulator

[image]

Result in browser (w3school editor)

[image]

There is difference of 1 line in both image for each line

Comment: hmmm i do not see any "<br>" tag in your question. Did I misunderstood your question ?

Comment: its coming form service in JSON  self.offerArray[indexPath.row][@"description"];, but you take any example its not working for any string even hard coded like  <br>

Comment: <h2><font color="gray”>Offer</font></h2>
    <b><font color="red">Offer 1:</font></b><br>
    <b>1 kg Sugar Free!</b><br>
    <p>Every purchase above 500 <br>
    valid till 23rd April</p>

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something wrong with your html, I did this by copy pasting your sample html and it is working fine for me.

```
NSString* html = @"<h2><font color=\"gray\">Offer</font></h2><b><font color=\"red\">Offer 1:</font></b><br><b>1 kg Sugar Free!</b><br><p>Every purchase above 500 <br>    valid till 23rd April</p>";
    NSString*kHTMLHeadOffer = @"<html><body>";

    NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@</body></html>",kHTMLHeadOffer,html];
    NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
    [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];
    lineLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

I had to add `"\"` to cater the qoutes after the `color` tag.
This is how it looks like for me
[image]

After reading your edited answer with added images , I tried the sample html you gave at w3school editor and it looks same as it looks in the simulator. Here is the SS for it

[image]

As you can see in the image, there is only just 1 break after the Heading Offer, not 2.

Comment: I think its not supporting the <h1> break when we take h1 in html its automatic give 1 break and another break should be of <br> tag so there must be be 2 line space but there is 1 only

Comment: I have uploaded my images please have a look there is difference between ios result and browser result

Comment: But it is giving break on its own after the heading tag, <h2><font color=\"gray\">Offer</font></h2> , after this there is no <br> tag but u can see the Offer1 text in the new line.

Comment: Yes but there is an extra line space in browser after <h2> but only 1 line space in iOS

Comment: strange see my w3school screen shot :(

Comment: Your first line seems incorrect because color is pink but it should be gray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108276/discussion-between-tarun-seera-and-abdul91).